# malloc not allocating memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

When debugging my code i see that it jumps into undefined portion of ram, seems that malloc not working. Here is the code that is intended to create a trampoline and hook a realFunction to fakeFunction.

```
void patch()
{
    PINT trampoline = (PINT)malloc(15);
    DWORD oldProtect;
    *((PBYTE)trampoline) = 0xE8;
    *((PDWORD)trampoline + 1) = ((DWORD)fakeFunction - (DWORD)trampoline -5);
    memcpy(trampoline, realFunction, 6);
    *((PDWORD)trampoline + 7) = 0xE9;
    *((PDWORD)trampoline + 8) = ((DWORD)fakeFunction - (DWORD)realFunction - 5);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)realFunction, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    *((PBYTE)realFunction) = 0xE9;
    *((PDWORD)realFunction + 1) = ((DWORD)trampoline - (DWORD)realFunction - 5);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)realFunction, 6, oldProtect, NULL);
}
```

**Update:** i solved the problem and here is the code explained:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void realFunction()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "realFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
}

void fakeFunction()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "fakeFunction()", "Trace", MB_OK);
}

//I wrote this generic function (although not using it below) to ease the writing to memory process
template<typename T>
void writeMemory(DWORD address, T value)
{
    *((T*)address) = value;
}

void main()
{
    BYTE originalPrologue[sizeof(DWORD[2])]; //Why DWORD[2]... meh it is just 2*4 = bytes not a big deal.
    DWORD oldProtection;
    DWORD addr = (DWORD)realFunction;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(DWORD[2]); i++) {
        originalPrologue[i] = (*(PBYTE)(addr + i));
    }

    //(DWORD)((DWORD)fakeFunction - (DWORD)realFunction - 5) note that we do target - source - 5, why - 5 ? because the size of jump instruction is 5, and the destination of jump is relative to it's address.
    //Implement Hook
    VirtualProtect(realFunction, sizeof(DWORD[3]), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
    *((PBYTE)addr) = 0xE9; E9 is JMP instruction
    *((PDWORD)(addr + 1)) = (DWORD)((DWORD)fakeFunction - (DWORD)realFunction - 5);
    VirtualProtect(realFunction, sizeof(DWORD[3]), oldProtection, NULL);

    realFunction(); //Boom, we now jump to our fake function instead of the original one.

    //Unimplement hook by restoring the original prologue
    VirtualProtect(realFunction, sizeof(DWORD[3]), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
    memcpy(realFunction, originalPrologue, sizeof(DWORD[2]));
    VirtualProtect(realFunction, sizeof(DWORD[3]), oldProtection, NULL);

    realFunction(); //Test it and we have the original function back!

    while (true){
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is rampant with undefined behavior. Assuming a DWORD is 4 bytes (most are on WIN32, but it only gets worse if its larger), you may want to think about what things like `(PDWORD)trampoline + 7` actually *does*. Pointer math says "Take address of a 15-byte allocation, offset 28 bytes from said-address, then use that to *write* a DWORD in indeterminate memory. I surmise that 15 should be mated with a `sizeof()` multiple of some kind. Check whatever site you purloined this from, chances are they didn't make the same mistakes. `malloc` is fine, its *your code* that hosed.

Comment: I have to agree with @WhozCraig. This is one of the scariest codes that I've seen in my life. Seriously...

Comment: i am still learning guys please bear with me, @WhozCraig so why offset 28 bytes from said address ?, malloc does create a space in the exe for us to write some custom code right ?

Comment: and yeah i am using numbers just in order to train myself it is not a code that will end up in anything :D

Comment: @DanielEugen it's typed *pointer arithmetic*, and if you don't know what that is, fire up the search engines, as you shouldn't be trying to manage pointers in C without a thorough understanding of the concept, *especially* in something like this.

Comment: @DanielEugen adding `7` to a pointer to `X` means to advance the pointer by `7` instances of `X`. (Not 7 bytes).

Comment: "i am still learning guys please bear with me", learning what? - this is an attempt at very advanced code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: learning pointers and function hooking... i already have 6 years of programming experience in C#, C++ is somehow new to me but i am getting my way into it.

Comment: @andlabs, i understand pointers pretty much good, what i want to do is copy the original function prologue to an allocated space in ram, then add a call to my fake function before it, and a call to the real function after it (after executing the real function's prologue)

Comment: @andlabs simply creating a trampoline to handle function hooking

Comment: But why are you making such a trampoline? If this is for your own program's use, just use a function pointer. (Yes, those exist in C++!)

Comment: @DanielEugen: you clearly DO NOT understand pointers, because you are making fundamental mistakes with them.  And you clearly do not understand the proper way to setup a function detour at all.  There are plenty of existing detouring libraries that handle the intricate details for you, you need to stop what you are doing and go pick one of them to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau no i want to learn how they work. yea i may do some mistakes but i am learning... i am just doing that for the sake of understanding things.

Comment: @andlabs i am just testing out with internal functions but then i will use the approach to hook external functions.

Comment: @andlabs i have updated the question JUST FOR THE BEGINNERS LIKE ME, so please stop treating people as if you are born with the knowledge.. instead of just closing up the doors in my face you might have helped with a code snippet or something... Same goes for others.

Answer (score 2):

This code is full of mistakes.  As pointed out in comments, you are not taking **pointer arithmetic** into account at all, so you are writing values at incorrect memory addresses.  You are also not doing any error handling, and you are not even setting up the detour and trampoline functions correctly to being with.  You clearly have not read the documentation of how a detour is actually implemented:

[Detours: Binary Interception of Win32 Functions](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=68568)

In particular:

> To detour a target function, Detours first allocates memory for the dynamic trampoline function (if no static trampoline is provided) and then enables write access to both the target and the trampoline. Starting with the first instruction, Detours copies instructions from the target to the trampoline until at least 5 bytes have been copied (enough for an unconditional jump instruction). If the target function is fewer than 5 bytes, Detours aborts and
>   returns an error code. To copy instructions, Detours uses a simple table-driven disassembler. Detours adds a jump instruction from the end of
>   the trampoline to the first non-copied instruction
>   of the target function. Detours writes an unconditional jump instruction to the detour function as the first instruction of the target
>   function. To finish, Detours restores the original page permissions on both the target and trampoline functions and flushes the CPU instruction cache with a call to FlushInstructionCache.

CPU instructions are variable-length.  Different instructions are different byte lengths. You might have to copy more than 5 bytes into your trampoline to account for complete instructions.  You cannot assume that exactly 6 bytes are used in every function, as you might end up copying a portion of a multi-byte instruction.  So you have to analyze the instructions of the original function that is being detoured and copy the correct number of bytes as needed so the trampoline always contains complete instructions, and then you have to insert the JMP instruction at the correct offset inside of the trampoline, and make it jump to the correct offset of the original function.

Worse, your trampoline is jumping into your detour function instead of the original function, and you are patching the original function to jump into your trampoline instead of your detour function.

In short, just about every line of this code is just plain doing the wrong thing at every step.  If you are going to tackle such an advanced technique, then at least be smart enough to use a pre-made library that saves you from making all of these mistakes.  Your bad code is risking major memory corruption and runtime errors.

Comment: This code is not going to be executed at the white house :D, i am just learning and btw i will understand things more better. That's why i ask you guys on stack overflow whenever i face a problem... and yeah i have been reading a lot about function hooking and memory addresses, and assembly and the example i provided here is just a rough try to make something work then i will refine it.

Comment: This is not the kind of code you should be learning programming from.  This is the kind of code you can write once you already know what you are doing (which you do not).  There are better and safer ways to learn how to program.

Comment: i am not learning how to program :D as i mentioned before i have been programming for 6 years in C# now and i pretty much know how a programming language work. However C++ is still a little bit strange to me as you know GC Collector was doing all the memo related staff for us in C# and Java

Comment: Look at the question now... and please don't be someone who just close up the doors. instead open em up for people because they might be really in need for that help. I have understood a little bit further and now i can copy the function's prologue and restore it after the hook. and i shared my knowledge so that others may benefit from it even if it is very small but it might help a beginner.

Comment: Your implementation is still broken and risky. Now you are copying 12 bytes instead of 6 bytes, which can easily be too many.  What if the target function is smaller than 12 bytes?  You are only going to be replacing 5 bytes, though you may need to copy more than 5 bytes into the trampoline. You MUST MUST MUST analyze the target function to calculate the correct number of bytes to copy, and the correct memory offsets to jump to.  You are not doing any of that.  People are not going to help you write dangerous code, and what you are doing is dangerous.